# vb.net webbrowser control, does not refresh htmltext

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

I have googled far and wide to the ends of china and the tip of south america... I cant seem to find a concrete solution to this common problem.

I am developing a google maps ap, and want to refresh the map with new detail on demand. The initial problem offcourse was that the webbrowser control does not reflect the changes (still keeps the original htmltext) and new document text and refresh. I understand the document text is set once, and cant be changed... apparently.

I have tried

```
navigate("about:blank") 
document.stop
document.new(true)
doevents
```

All the collected user knowledge on this problem, only get me half way. I can get the page refreshed using some of the techniques above, but it then gives me a script error and an error 53, which both has no details or origins.. just blank errors.... after clicking through their error windows, my page refreshes.

Can anyone shed some light on a clear cut solution. Can it really be this big of an issue?

P.S. I don't know if my javascript events that are bound to the webbrowser control causes the errors. Some have suggested that the errors are due to the document loading without all its references being closed/open...

Can someone please save me from insanity.

Answer (score 0):

Louis, how are you mate? I understand how WB control issues can be deal breakers, I will help you out until we solve this issue. However, could you tell me more about the HTMLText and DocumentText and what you mean by them? are they properties of the WB control? I'm using a pre-.NET WB control, it is still mainly the same thing but the .NET one has a few more fancy properties & methods :).

Ok, first thing is first, are you SURE this new data exchange isn't happening inside a frame or an iframe? Hence, you are not able to see any change in the HTML text of the top-level html document/page? I have a function which recursively grabs references to all the frames on the page, and all the frames in those frames, being every single frame and all nested frames up to infinite-depth. That might be able to help you.

Also, what are you using to get the text? The html document is a LIVE document, in that, as elements change, the DOM changes, and what you read from the DOM will also be updated, it is a 100% live document, and as long as you are declaring your document as a MSHTML.IHTMLDocument then you should be good to go.

Most importantly, I didn't hear you mention .innerText, .outerText, .innerHTML and .outerHTML. These are of course the items you want to be retreiving text/source from. If you want the full pages, check those properties out! So, if you want the Text inside the BODY tags, you would do the following:

Say, out IHTMLDocument object is called hDoc.

```
MsgBox hDoc.body.innerText
```

That will show you only the text inside the BODY tags, to get the HTML inside the BODY tags, just do this.

```
MsgBox hDoc.body.innerHTML
```

Now, if you want the HTML in the BODY tags while also retreiving the starting and closing BODY tags, then you'd do this:

```
MsgBox hDoc.body.outerHTML
```

... etc...

Of course, if you want to refresh the document for whatever reason, there is a refresh method of the webbrowser control, it's WebBrowser1.Refresh and I think there is a .Refresh2 which has slightly different refresh logic.

I can go on and on, but would like to know I've understood your question correctly before we do. Now, the only thing that changes is the live Image of the map inside the webbrowser control, doesn't it? Perhaps some text around it as well like address/etc? Or is it just the image data that changes (been a while since I used google maps, and not sure which implementation you are using), so if you could let me know what exactly changes and what you are trying to pick up/read, I should be able to help you better, all in all, I promise to hold your hand until we figure this thing out (lol) - cheers mate, let me know how it goes.

Erx.

Comment: Hi Erx.

I definately treid the refresh, that was first point of call. Spent an hour looking for issues with my code.... which was when I dicsovered that its the control thats not updating, not my code malfunctioning :-) . I am generating the complete html doc code from a class, including the javascript for the maps api and markers etc. You can take the class output html, stick it in an empy file, and the map will work as generated.

Comment: So basically, on a new maker ad, I want to update the compelte page in the browser component, with a complete new page. I initially se the page's htmltext = output from my class (the whole doc text). ON resetting htmltext and refreshing, its not updated. The rest, as in ym first post.

Comment: @Louis van Tonder Im now curious, are you actually trying to change the value in the HtmlText & hoping that changing that will change/update the html? If so, it won't. You will need to go through all of the elements in the DOM & change/update them one by one if you want to programmatically change the document. So get a reference to the IHTMLDocument2 (top level html page) and go through all the elements if you need too, from 0 to myDoc.All.length -1   - i can tell you how to do this if you are new to the document object, let me know if you were actually trying to change the html text directly.

Comment: HI, no I am not trying to "modify" any of the html objects. I am generating a ccomplete new html document (from doctype to /body). I want to in all instances of the phrase, completely re-load the web browser control with said new html file (as text). I don;t want to navigate to a physical temp file, I need to lass the html file text as a string, as in my first inital load of the brwoser control.

Comment: @Louis van Tonder as a WB person, i want to know what you want to do from a WB perspective, i'll just tell you what i've understood from your questions, & if im correct, you want to give the WB control a pre-made HTML as a String, and have the WB control render that HTML String, is that right? So, you have the HTML String & there are no problems with generating the HTML string? However, you don't want to write it to a file and do a .navigate to that file, am i right? if i am right in my understanding, may i ask why? (you dont need to answer that, but just curious as there may be another way).

Comment: Correct. Regarding temp file, I don't want to use a temporary html files, because I think its sloppy and unnececary. Multiple users on same exe accidentally accessing shared files etc etc. I have been down that route before, and I prefer not to have temp files.

Comment: THe html doc contains javscript routines to create custom markers etc. So I have to re generate the map, on lets say, a new marker being added, or forcing an update iuf someone else had added a marker in the db.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder I think there is a way to do it, create a .html file on your server, with the html and body tags placed, then add a div tag inside the body tag, then once you generate the HTML on your client, set the div tags innerHtml equals to the html you generated, then it will display & render your html on the fly in real time (a way to trick the browser to do what you want). also, re temp files, it aint that bad. if you go down that route, get the environ("temp") folder using the environment variable, then generate a random word and save that (say) 6 character word as a html file...

Comment: @LouisvanTonder ... of course, before saving the html file on disk, check to make sure that a html file under that 6 character temp file does not exist, in the extreamly unlikely case that it does, just generate another one, like in a do loop until [6CharWord].html does not exist, and it will only run once and at most twice (the loop) and your problems are solved. but you dont need to use this option, you can edit html live in the wb control, so just use an editing method to inject the html you want onto a mock somewhat-empty page that you have pre-made and hosted on a server somewhere. cool?

Comment: Hey, thanks, problem is, the javascript in the head also changes, the div actually does not "have" any content. Content is only injected into the div by the google scripts in the head, and the google scripts change depending on the amount of markers.